# How can an execute_script line work when run in a debugger but not when in the script itself?

Tags: ruby, testing, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

I have the following (mildly-anonymised) `evaluate_script` line in a javascript capybara test, within a ruby rspec:

```
page.execute_script("$('selector').addClass('-class')")
```

It isn't working, e.g. the following prints `false` :

```
page.execute_script("console.log($('selector').hasClass('-class')")
```

If I put a debugger (`binding.pry`) after that line, and then run the `addClass` line in the debugger -- literally the same line that's just executed; copied and pasted -- then it *does* work.

It doesn't seem to be a timing issue -- putting `sleep`s after the `addClass` line doesn't change anything.

It's very repeatable: the exact line that doesn't do anything in the script then suddenly works if I replace it with a `binding.pry` and run the line from pry. Which AFAIK should be impossible.

So: what could cause the same thing to work when run from a debugger, and not when run not from the debugger?

Capybara driver is poltergeist on phantomJS.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so turns out it was a timing issue after all.

I had been assuming that an addClass call would work no matter when in page load it was done, as long as jQuery was loaded and the element was present, which they were.

Which means while I'd tried adding a sleep after the `addClass`, in case it was a race condition between adding a class and testing for it - what I *hadn't* tried was putting a sleep *before* adding the class. Which fixed it. So apparently that assumption was false.

So the difference running the line from the debugger made was just that it gave it a few seconds before running it!

To avoid sleeping a random amount of time, I added a spinner:

```
def spin_until_thing_done(selector)
  Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_wait_time) do
    loop do
      do_thing(selector)
      return if thing_done?(selector)
      sleep 0.1
    end
  end
end

def do_thing(selector)
  page.execute_script("$('#{selector}').addClass('-class')")
end

def thing_done?(selector)
  page.evaluate_script("$('#{selector}').hasClass('-clas')")
end
```